# Custom Control Enum property problems

Tags: c#, asp.net, custom-controls

I have a solution with two projects:

- `CustomControls` has custom controls (.cs files)
- `WebPages` has aspx pages

One of the controls has a property like this:

---- Defined in  `Platform.CustomControls` namespace -------

```
[Category("Search Mode"),
DefaultValue(SearchTextBoxModeEnum.global),
Personalizable(PersonalizationScope.Shared),
TypeConverter("String"),
WebBrowsable(true),
WebDisplayName("SearchTextBoxMode"),
WebDescription("SearchTextBoxMode")]

public SearchTextBoxModeEnum SearchTextBoxMode
{
  set;
  get;
}
```

---- Defined in  `Platform.CustomControls.Interface` namespace -------

```
public enum SearchTextBoxModeEnum
{
  global,
  forms,
  products,
  internet
}
```

This project builds successfully.

When I reference this project in my Webpage project and add the property in the control markup, all the other enums appear but "internet" does not appears in intellisense.

```
<Platform:searchtextbox id="SearchTextBox3" runat="server" SearchTextBoxMode="internet"   pagename="xyz">
</OnlinePlatform:ecmssearchtextbox>
```

I get an error while running the page in a browser:

> Cannot create an object of type Platform.CustomControls.Interface.SearchTextBoxModeEnum' from its string representation 'internet' for the 'SearchTextBoxMode' property.

I checked all the details with the added reference (in object browser and ILDASM.exe and I can see the property).

Comment: I suspect there is a part of code where the `SearchTextBoxModeEnum` is being parsed. Look for all the references of this Enum.

Comment: Thanks for reply. But rest of the properties are coming fine. I'm not doing anything else other than adding it to SearchTextBoxEnum. Atleast I should get it in the intellisense in the code markup.

Comment: Ok. But what if somewhere in the project there is, for a example a switch statement, on the enum values? Now that you added 'internet', you should add a section of code for this new value into consideration. Press Shift+F12 on the enum and check all its references

Comment: Ok. using this as `SearchTextBoxModeEnum.internet.ToString()` as like other properties

Comment: Sounds like an issue with the TypeConverter...  can you try without it temporarily just to test?

Comment: It is still throwing the same error...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the enum property.
VS2012 isn't able to render forms with custom controls that have enum properties.

I've signaled this issue to Microsoft about 1k times, with no answer.